# Indexed families and subsets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Having some trouble being able to do this question and would really appreciate some help with it.

[image]

Perhaps I would say that for 1. that the union for i belonging to I that Ai = {x | x belonging to Ai for at least i belonging to I} and

the intersection for i belonging to I that Bi = {x | x belonging to Bi for every i belonging to I}

I am still quite lost on how to solve this though.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You should assume that $x$ is some element in $\bigcup_{i\in I} (A_i - B_i)$ and then show that it must also be an element of $\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i - \bigcap_{i\in I} B_i\right)$.

Possible solution:

> If $x \in \bigcup_{i\in I} (A_i - B_i)$, there exists some $k$, such that $x\in(A_k-B_k)$. This means that $x\in A_k$ and $x\not\in B_k$. It follows that $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$, since this is the union of all $A_i$, and that $x\not\in \bigcap_{i\in I} B_i$ as it is not in all $B_i$ (in particular, $x\not\in B_k$). Thus we have $x\in \left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i - \bigcap_{i\in I} B_i\right)$.